# VB2010 Index was outside the bounds of the array when editing file

Tags: vb.net

Im making a flight booking system where the user can choose a seat on the flight and it will edit a file with their information. (csv format)

```
  Public DestinationTick As String
    Public PlaneTick As String
    Public TimeTick As String
    Public NameTick As String
    Public DayTick As String
    Public Stockitems() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("AM830.csv")
    Public SortedStock(Stockitems.Length - 1)
    Public Stocktypes(Stockitems.Length - 1) As Flight

    Public Structure Flight
        Public Destination As String
        Public Plane As String
        Public Time As String
        Public Name As String
        Public Day As String
        Public Address As String
    End Structure


''' Code when i press the confirm button
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText("AM830.csv", "")
        If P1A1.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            Stocktypes(0).Destination = GlobalDestination ''''Error here
            Stocktypes(0).Plane = GlobalPlane
            Stocktypes(0).Time = GLobalTime
            Stocktypes(0).Name = GlobalName
            Stocktypes(0).Day = GlobalDay
            Stocktypes(0).Address = GlobalAddress
            P1A1.Enabled = False
        End If
```

When i run the program and press on the button P1A1 to choose the seat and press Confirm, it gives an error at Stocktypes(0).Destination = GlobalDestination "index was outside the bounds of the array". Have i structured it wrong? my teacher used basically the same code except his program runs on one form.

Comment: Where are all those declarations at the top located?  You cant initialize `Stockitems` with executable code.  Use the constructor.

Comment: The 2 at the top are in a seperate module.

What do you mean by i cant initialize stockitems with exe code?

Never heard of the constructor...

Comment: If `Stocktypes(0)` gets an exception because the index (0) is outside the bounds of the array, that means that the `StockTypes` array is empty (it has zero elements). You show a statement that reads the lines from the file "AM830.csv" into the `StockTypes` array. I can only assume that the file contains no lines at the time that statement is executed, or the array has been changed at some time after that.